# STRINGdb: reverse map STRING identifiers to gene names?

Tags: r, bioconductor, networks, stringdb

Is there a functionality within STRINGdb package or in another environment to reverse map the STRING identifiers to Gene names?

For example, the entire STRING network can be downloaded using the commands:

```
library(STRINGdb)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new(version="11", species=9606,
                          score_threshold=0, input_directory="" )
full.graph <- string_db$load_all()
netFull
# IGRAPH c07d6e9 UN-- 19354 11759454 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), combined_score (e/n)
# + edges from c07d6e9 (vertex names):
#  [1] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000272298 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000253401
#  [3] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000401445 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000418915
#  [5] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000327801 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000466298
#  [7] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000232564 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000393379
#  [9] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000371253 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000373713
# [11] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000248929 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000356737
# [13] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000338766 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000386135
# [15] 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000319192 9606.ENSP00000000233--9606.ENSP00000432568
# + ... omitted several edges
```

`V(netFull)$name` will provide all the STRING identifiers within this network `netFull`. How to get the corresponding gene names?

For example, `string_db$map()` maps the gene identifiers of the input dataframe to STRING identifiers. It returns the input dataframe with the "STRING_id" as an additional column. Now, I would like to explore in the reverse direction going from STRING identifiers to gene names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's too late, but I met same question and got an answer.
You can use `add_proteins_description()`. It works in same way with `map()`. If you put a data frame having `STRING_id` column, it adds `preferred_name`, `protein_size` and `annotation`. You may find your answer on `preferred_name` column.

```
require(STRINGdb)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new()
string_db$add_proteins_description(data.frame(STRING_id = [vector containing string ids]))
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not rely on STRINGdb package.

STRING provides supplementary identifier mapping files here: https://string-db.org/mapping_files/.

It looks like you are interested in human STRING name one - https://string-db.org/mapping_files/STRING_display_names/human.name_2_string.tsv.gz. You could read it as a separate lookup.